# Can names in unnamed namespaces in different C++ files refer to the same named thing?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Clang and GCC have a difference of opinion in this problem:

With g++ "result2" is printed, but with clang++ it's "result1".

I know g++ think the `A` thrown by `g()`, is not the same `A` is the main.cpp.
But, is there has anything wrong with clang++?

version:
g++: 7.4.0
clang: 10.0.0

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
  struct A {};
}

extern void g();

int main()
{
  try {
    try {
      g();
    } catch (A) {std::cout << "result1\n";}
  } catch (...) {std::cout << "result2\n";}
}
```

other.cpp:

```
namespace {
  struct A {};
}

void g() { throw A(); }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should change your question to "Which is correct according to the C++ 2017 standard?", to make it more general.

Comment: It should always be result2 as unnamed namespaces make type local to translation unit.

Answer (score 6):

The names `A` have **internal linkage** here; they can’t possibly refer to the same thing in different translation units.  GCC is correct in this case; some implementations use names to implement RTTI, which may be at fault here.

Comment: _they can’t possibly refer to the same thing in different translation units_ Hmmm. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.link#9 says _Two names that are the same and that are declared in different scopes shall denote the same variable, function, type, template or namespace **if**…_, but there is no _**and only if**_ following _**if**_.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: See (the unfortunately vague) [basic.link/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3) and [CWG1884](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1884): this paragraph should not be read as *specifying* when two declarations declare the same entity.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I noticed if we write same code but using named namespace, both clang and g++ print `result1`. is this logical completely? I thought I should get a redefinition at least.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah, I think I've misread [basic.link]/9. It says _"Two names that are the same and that are **declared**"_. I've overlooked this **declared** (or rather read it as something like **used/mentioned**) and thought that this paragraph applies to `A` in `throw A();` and `A` in `catch (A)`.